# How to update my own theme?

Tags: theme-development, themes

I've created my own theme and I updated like following.

1. Zip my local theme.
2. Upload the zip file to wordpress themes directory in server.
3. Set wordpress theme to default(twentythirteen).
4. login to server and `cd` to wordpress themes directory.
5. `rm -rf mytheme; unzip mytheme.zip`
6. Change theme to "mytheme" again.

I think this is little complicated. Is there way that I can do it more easily?

Especially I want to omit "change theme setting" parts ("3" and "6"). Removing and Unzip take only per second at most. I don't care if my site shows error page in that short time.

Comment: Just skip _the changing theme back and forth_ steps. One doesn't have to change the theme to a default theme in order to update the current theme!

Comment: FTP the theme files to the server. No need for the zipping and unzipping.

Comment: @Pothi I thought it maybe cause a problem if there is a access between deleting and copying. If it is ok, I'll skip it. Thanks!

Comment: @s_ha_dum To make shorter the time that "there is no theme", I've used zip actions. But if you think it is needless I'll do it without `zip`. Thanks for your advice!